# If more then one html5 video on page ,they can not be load successfully

Tags: load, html5-video

In test page ,I write 5 html5 video file on the page ,like :

```
<video controls="controls"><source src="v1.m4v"></video>
<video controls="controls"><source src="v2.m4v"></video>
<video controls="controls"><source src="v3.m4v"></video>
<video controls="controls"><source src="v4.m4v"></video>
<video controls="controls"><source src="v5.m4v"></video>
```

But when open the page only the first video could be load. The other four is just black,or sometime the five are all black.When I there only one video on the page, it could be load successfully.

So I think maybe there is a limit on page load video file number?

My solution is put all video into a queue, only when the previous video load event completed, the next video load event is allow begin(using `load()`).But how can I know the previous video load event complete?

Comment: Just curious, have you tried to put all 5 in seperate iframes? Not sure if it'd matter.

Comment: @JustCallMeNew: no, my web application is need the video in top window DOM, not in iframe, so even in seperate iframe could work,it make no sense to me

Comment: Did you try if it works better with proper structure, i.e., closing the `source` elements, as in `<video controls="controls"><source src="v1.m4v" /></video>`?

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig:In fact I closing the `source` in html markup already, the code above is copy from chrome developer tools